# pyvisa-py on raspberry pi AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ResourceManager'

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi3, pyvisa

py on a raspberry pi with python 2.7.9 and pip 1.5.6. I installed and uninstalled pyvisa and pyvisa-py several times, but the problems stay. I connected the KEITHLEY Multimeter 2000 per R232 to USB with the Raspberry.

When I run the basic Code:

`import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager('@py')
a=rm.list_resources()
print(a)`

I receive:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyvisa.py", line 1, in <module>
    import visa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visa.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pyvisa import logger, __version__, log_to_screen, constants
  File "/home/pi/pyvisa.py", line 2, in <module>
    rm = visa.ResourceManager('@py')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ResourceManager'`

as well when I try

`python -m visa info`

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visa.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pyvisa import logger, __version__, log_to_screen, constants
  File "pyvisa.py", line 1, in <module>
    import visa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/visa.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pyvisa import logger, __version__, log_to_screen, constants
ImportError: cannot import name logger`

On the other hand i can't upgrade, because the requirements are already up-to-date.

`pip install pyvisa-py --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: pyvisa-py in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: pyvisa>=1.8 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyvisa-py)
Requirement already up-to-date: enum34 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from pyvisa>=1.8->pyvisa-py)`

I would be very thankfull if somebody could help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

visa.py module does not have ResourceManager() you must instead use pyvsa.py

```
import pyvisa

rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager('@py')
a=rm.list_resources()
print(a)
```

There will be no error if you run this code, you should be able to print whatever instrument is connected.

Answer (score 0):

"In python 2.7, the import system will always use files in the working directory over the one in site-packages and as your file is named pyvisa.py when importing visa.py it picks your own module instead of the 'real' pyvisa module."MatthieuDartiailh from github